# Is there any way to survive solarwinter like in Sunshine - movie?

Tags: astrophysics

Is there any way to survive solarwinter like in Sunshine - movie?
Solar winter is where for some reason sun looses its capasity to produce radiation( heat etc.). It doesn't loose everything but some of its radiation energy( say 50 %) That causes earth to cool down causing next "ice age"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Food could be grown using UV lights, powered by nuclear fission.

We could probably do it.

But it would be the spece equivalent of a human being on a life support machine - all our time and energy would be consumed just with survival, so while humans as a species might survive, our society, culture and science would probably slow down to a crawl, or disappear completely. Most other species would die off, so it would be a pretty dismal future.

Answer (score 2):

Currently all life lives off of the sun's energy, at least indirectly. One possible exception is some types of bacteria that need only heat energy plus some inorganic chemicals that abound in the ocean - those would be fine as long as the Earth is geologically active.

For us, however, it would be curtains, within months or several years at best. You could watch the movie The Road for at least one potential scenario where this happens (in the form of nuclear winter, where cloud cover never lets the sun through) - not good.

Energy would remain available for a long time to come - fossil fuels, nuclear fission fuels, and then even more if we figure out fusion. But a big question would be where do we get our food. Currently, science does not know how to keep humans alive without at least some input from the biosphere in the form of calories and minerals. Food is chemically complex, and we haven't fully characterized it yet, and don't know how to synthesize it. Because of that reason mostly, we would be doomed if the sun took a several-years nap. Since there's a lot of food stored around the earth, a lot of people would find ways to survive for a while - but the inevitable would be that once those thermophilic bacteria are the only other living creatures, and we've eaten up all canned food - we would be finished.

Interesting question! Whenever the answer to this becomes "yes we could survive" it would mean we are capable of surviving in the dead of space - which for me would mean a new level of evolution for our species.