# Is there any way to produce food without sun, synthetically?

Tags: astrophysics

Is there any way to produce food without sun, synthetically? I mean if we face solar winter. look at: [Is there any way to survive solarwinter like in Sunshine - movie?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30095/is-there-any-way-to-survive-solarwinter-like-in-sunshine-movie)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You make artificial light with the same spectrum as the sun, and shine it on the crops.

Comment: There are even special suppliers able to fit a system into a house or truck http://www.growopltd.com/products/GrowOp-Porta-Grow-Tent-4x8.html